# Finding URL by regex

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to find URL in array of strings.

This is my code:

```
if((reti = regcomp(&reg, "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\w\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,6}\.?)(\/[\w\.]*)*\/?$/", 0)) == 0)
{
    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
        cout << "lllll" << endl;
        reti = regexec(&reg, argv[i], 0, NULL, 0);
        if(!reti)
        {
            regfree(&reg);
            return static_cast<string>(argv[i]);
        }

    }


}else
{

    cerr << "Cannot compile regex" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
regfree(&reg);
```

But it couldn't find URL, could anybody explain me, where is mistake?

Comment: Whew! That's a regex! You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gZ0kE2/2) but we can't do too much but speculate until you give us some sample data. Paste it into the OP, please.

Comment: Looking at your code, there is no way it is compiled correctly, since you are using `regex.h` header, which doesn't need `/` as delimiter. Furthermore, you need to double up `\` in string literal, otherwise, the regex engine doesn't see it. Also, `\w` doesn't work on all systems with POSIX regex implementation. I can't fathom why you accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

Explanation:

First, it searches for the beginning of the line with the caret.

The first capturing group allows the URL to begin with "http://", "https://", or neither of them. The question mark after the `s` allows URL's that have http or https. In order to make this entire group optional, there is also a question mark to the end of it.

Next is the domain name: one or more numbers, letters, dots, or hyphens followed by another dot then two to six letters or dots.

The following part handles optional files and directories. Inside the group, we want to match any number of forward slashes, letters, numbers, underscores, spaces, dots, or hyphens. And indicate this group can be matched as many times as needed, allowing multiple directories to be matched along with a file at the end.

I used the star instead of the question mark because the star says zero or more, not zero or one. If a question mark was to be used there, only one file/directory would be able to be matched.

Then a trailing slash is matched, but it can be optional. Finally we end with the end of the line.

[Reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)